# Type conversion: signed int to unsigned long in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm currently up to chapter 2 in The C Programming Language (K&R) and reading about bitwise operations.

This is the example that sparked my curiosity:

```
x = x & ~077
```

**Assuming a 16-bit word length and 32-bit long type**, what I think would happen is 077 would first be converted to:

```
0000 0000 0011 1111 (16 bit signed int).
```

This would then be complemented to:

```
1111 1111 1100 0000.
```

My question is what would happen next for the different possible types of x? If x is a signed int the answer is trivial. But, if x is a signed long I'm assuming ~077 would become:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 0000
```

following 2s complement to preserve the sign. Is this correct?

Also, if x is an unsigned long will ~077 become:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1100 0000
```

Or, will ~077 be converted to a signed long first:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 0000
```

...after which it is converted to an unsigned long (no change to bits)?

Any help would help me clarify whether or not this operation will **always** set only the last 6 bits to zero.

Comment: You can probably do this test yourself by either using a debugger to view values or printing out the values yourself. You can also look at the C language specification. Figure out which specification your compiler supposedly implements and then look up the details in the corresponding spec. "Integer promotion" is probably what you want to look for. FWIW, I believe in C that integer promotion should not change the value. So you'd probably get a sign-extended value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever data-type you choose, `~077` will set the rightmost 6 bits to `0` and all others to `1`.

Assuming 16-bit `int`s and 32-bit `long`s, there are 4 cases:

Case 1

```
unsigned int x = 077; // x = 0000 0000 0011 1111
x = ~x; // x = 1111 1111 1100 0000
unsigned long y = ~x; // y = 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1100 0000
```

Case 2

```
unsigned int x = 077; // x = 0000 0000 0011 1111
x = ~x; // x = 1111 1111 1100 0000
long y = ~x; // y = 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1100 0000
```

Case 3

```
int x = 077; // x = 0000 0000 0011 1111
x = ~x; // x = 1111 1111 1100 0000
unsigned long y = ~x; // y = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 0000
```

Case 4

```
int x = 077; // x = 0000 0000 0011 1111
x = ~x; // x = 1111 1111 1100 0000
long y = ~x; // y = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 0000
```

See code [here](http://ideone.com/8n9QmG). This means the sign extension is done when the source is `signed`. When the source is `unsigned`, sign bit is not extended and the left bits are set to `0`.

Comment: But what happens if ~077 is a signed int which is then ANDed with an unsigned long?

Comment: What about: int x = 077; x = ~x; unsigned long y = x; What is y?

Comment: OK, I think I've got it. But what is the point of sign extension when converting from signed to an unsigned, as in case 3? Do you know where I can find the actual C specifications for this?

Comment: Found [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/signExt.html) after some googling, hope it helps :)

And "_When an integer with a negative sign is promoted to an unsigned integer of the same or larger type, it is first promoted to the signed equivalent of the larger type, then converted to the unsigned value._" from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjamz/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
 x = x & ~077    //~077=11111111111111111111111111000000(not in every case)
```

`~077 is a constant evaluated at the complie time so its value will be casted according to the value of x at the compile time` so the AND operation will always yield to last 6 bits of x to 0 and the remaining bits will remain whatever they were before the AND operation. Like

```
//let x=256472--> Binary--> 0000 0000 0000 0011 1110 1001 1101 1000
 x = x & ~077;
// now x = 0000 0000 0000 0011 1110 1001 1100 0000 Decimal--> 256448
```

So the last 6 bits are changed to 0 irrespective of the data type during the compile time remaining bits remain same. And in knr it is written there `The portable form
involves no extra cost, since ~077 is a constant expression that can be evaluated at compile time.`